# Set up a task after a series of clicks

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an application centered around Google Maps and for one of the features the user will input a series of clicks in order to create a polygon. I would like to do something with the information after the clicks but I don't know how to accomplish this without `setTimeout()` which wouldn't work due to the variable amount of time it could take the users to create the polygon.

Currently my code is structured as such (with help from one of the answers on the question [Draw polygon using mouse on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325670/draw-polygon-using-mouse-on-google-maps).

```
let polygons = [];

$('.set-polygon').click(function () {
    let isClosed = false;

    let poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        path: [],
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
        if (isClosed) {
            return;
        }

        let markerIndex = poly.getPath().length;
        let isFirstMarker = markerIndex === 0;

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: e.latLng,
            draggable: true
        });

        if (isFirstMarker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                if (isClosed) {
                    return;
                }

                let path = poly.getPath();

                poly.setMap(null);
                poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    map: map,
                    path: path,
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#FF0000",
                    fillOpacity: 0.35
                });

                isClosed = true;
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (e) {
            poly.getPath().setAt(markerIndex, e.latLng);
        });

        poly.getPath().push(e.latLng);

        let params = {
            name: "Polygon1",
            poly: poly
        };
        polygons.push(params);

        console.log(polygons);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you check the last point of click has the same coordinates as the first one? or at least if the 2 are within a certain distance, then you would end the drawing?

Comment: The drawing ends by itself when the user connects the line to the first place clicked but there's no event for that.